# Emberjs - how to access method of one controller from another controller'

Tags: controller, ember.js

In emberjs **pre2** we could access controller or any method in controller from another controller in
following way:

**App.get('router').get('navController').method1();**

Can anybody suggest what could be the similar code for emberjs **rc1**?

Thanks

Comment: I've been trying to follow Data down actions up paradigm.  How you would do something similar is using the dependency injection @Def_Os suggested, but do it on the application route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a `Controller` or a `Route` you can try

```
this.controllerFor("nav").method1()
```

---

## Attention

This was correct answer when the question was asked but since `controllerFor` is deprecated, please check the answer by [joscas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15644092/1482899)

Comment: Is there any way to call controller method from view?

Comment: Try this.get("controller").method1() to access controller method from view

Comment: `DEPRECATION: Controller#controllerFor is deprecated, please use Controller#needs instead`

Answer (score 17):

Since `controllerFor` is deprecated, I think the a more correct way would be with *needs*:

```
this.get('controllers.nav').method1()
```

It requires declaring your *needs* in your controller:

```
App.YourController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['nav'],
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ember 2, this works by *injecting* the controller you want access to:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  nav: Ember.inject.controller(),
});
```

Or, if you want to specify a name different than the controller name:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  navController: Ember.inject.controller('nav'),
});
```

You can then access the injected controller's methods like this:

```
this.get('navController').method1()
```

Comment: I've been trying to follow Data down actions up paradigm.  How you would do something similar is using the dependency injection @Def_Os suggested, but do it on the application route.

Then instead of calling the method directly, just send the action and let it bubble up to the application route.  This avoids the complicated direct dependency between the 2 controllers that can be hard to manage in large projects.